# couldn't find javascript file on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a namespace in routes file, and I can't load js and css file.

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'publikum/benutzer#index'
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via =>[:post,:get,:patch,:delete]
  namespace :admin do
    root to: 'benutzer#index'
  end

end
```

benutzer.js

```
//=require common-scripts.js
#and 
//=require admin-component/etc
```

[my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqG51.png)

result:

```
couldn't find file 'common-scripts.js' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Comment: try this `//=require ./common-scripts.js`

Comment: why can't use //=require common-scripts.js or //=require admin-component/etc ,on rails 4 this working 

Comment: please answer my question until vote and accept your question 